# Can anyone tell me why my generated HTML is not working with this XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have the below XSLT, but when it runs, it creates the below HTML. The problem is with the two tables. The `LinesFOC` elements appear within the first table instead of the second table as per the XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Order Received</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <th>Outlet</th>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Order/Outlet/Name"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>House Name / Number</th>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Order/Outlet/HouseNameNumber"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Street Name</th>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Order/Outlet/Street1"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Order/Outlet/Street2"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Order/Outlet/Street3"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Suburb</th>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Order/Outlet/Suburb"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Town</th>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Order/Outlet/Town"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>County</th>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Order/Outlet/County"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Postcode</th>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Order/Outlet/Postcode"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Telephone Number</th>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Order/Outlet/TelephoneNumber"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Contact Name</th>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Order/Outlet/ContactName"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>UWG Account Number</th>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Order/Outlet/UWGAccountNumber"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Cash or Credit</th>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Order/Outlet/CashOrCredit"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Order Date</th>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Order/Date"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Description</th>
          </tr>

          <xsl:for-each select="Order/Lines/LineItem">
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="Qty"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="Description"/></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>

        </table>

        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <td></td>
            <td>Free of Charge Items</td>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="Order/LinesFOC/LineItem">
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="Qty"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="Description"/></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>

      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The generated HTML is

```
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="1" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b>Outlet </b></p>
      </td>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal">Test Outlet 4</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b>House Name / Number
        </b></p>
      </td>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal">Test House</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b>Street Name </b>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal">Test Street</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt"></td>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt"></td>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b>Suburb </b></p>
      </td>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal">Testtown</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b>Town </b></p>
      </td>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal">Testtown</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b>County </b></p>
      </td>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal">Cardiganshire</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b>Postcode </b></p>
      </td>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal">GU21 </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b>Telephone Number
        </b></p>
      </td>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b>Contact Name </b>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b>UWG Account Number
        </b></p>
      </td>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal">55555555555</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b>Cash or Credit </b>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b>Order Date </b></p>
      </td>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal">05/06/2013 00:00:00</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background:yellowgreen; padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b>Qty</b></p>
      </td>
      <td style="background:yellowgreen; padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b>Description</b></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal">3</p>
      </td>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal"> Chocolate 1L (110717)</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal">3</p>
      </td>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal"> Strawberry 1L (110645)</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal">3</p>
      </td>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal"> Banana 1L (110656)</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal">3</p>
      </td>
      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal"> Strawberry 1L (110645) </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="">&nbsp;</span></p>

<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="1" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="background:yellowgreen; padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt"></td>
      <td style="background:yellowgreen; padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal">Free of Charge Items </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

the last item of the first table, being:

```
<tr>
  <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
    <p class="MsoNormal">3</p>
  </td>
  <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
    <p class="MsoNormal"> Strawberry 1L (110645) </p>
  </td>
</tr>
```

should be on the second table, but for some reason, appears in the first table.

Comment: I don't see what the output has to do with xlst. In my few this xslt has never generated the output. Also the input xml is needed.

Comment: That output has definitely not been produced by the stylesheet you show. For one thing the output `td` elements have `style` attributes, which they do not have in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to say for sure what's going on, in the current state of the question.  The two most likely causes are these.

(1) The input (which you do not show) has

```
<LineItem>
  <Qty>3</Qty>
  <Description> Strawberry 1L (110645) </Description>
</LineItem>
```

appearing as a child of Lines, not as a child of LinesFOC.

(2) The stylesheet which actually produced the output (which, as hr_117 and Borodin have already pointed out, you do not show) has `<xsl:for-each select="Order/Lines/LineItem">` (or the equivalent) where the stylesheet you show has `<xsl:for-each select="Order/LinesFOC/LineItem">`.

In other words, you appear to be looking at the wrong files.